# Sacar el nombre del archivo en Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy trabajando en un programa el cual descarga los vídeo de youtube y los convierte a archivo de audio de cualquier formato, ya sea por dándole un enlace o un término de búsqueda y tengo un problema con la recogida del nombre del archivo descargado, ya que se puede descargar en diversos formatos de vídeo (principalmente mkv, mp4, webm).

Lo único que consigo es que el nombre concuerde parseando el nombre del vídeo desde la página pero me sigue faltando el formato de salida. Hasta ahora tengo esa parte del código así:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request, urllib.parse
import subprocess
import ffmpy
import requests


def name_generator(term):
    url = term
    webpage_url = "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + url.replace(" ", "+")
    webpage_url = urllib.parse.quote(webpage_url, safe='/:?+=', encoding="utf-8", errors="strict")
    webpage_request = urllib.request.urlopen(webpage_url)
    status_code = webpage_request.getcode()

    if status_code == 200:
        list_of_names = []
        html = BeautifulSoup(webpage_request, "html.parser")
        videos = html.find_all('div', {'class': 'yt-lockup-content'})
        for i, video in enumerate(videos):
            if len(list_of_names) < 5:
                name = video.find('a')['title']
                formatted_text = "{0}".format(name)
                list_of_names.append(formatted_text)

    return list_of_names


url = input("Introduce la URL: ")
comando = "youtube-dl {} -o %(title)s.%(ext)s".format(url)
subprocess.call(comando, shell=True)
question = input("Quieres convertir el audio?[S/n]: ").lower()
if question == "s":
    request = input("En que formato lo quires?: ")
    nombre = name_generator(url)[0]
    try:
        ff=ffmpy.FFmpeg(
            inputs={"{}.mp4".format(nombre): None},
            outputs={"{}.{}".format(nombre, request): None}
        )
        ff.run()
    except:
        ff=ffmpy.FFmpeg(
            inputs={"{}.webm".format(nombre): None},
            outputs={"{}.{}".format(nombre, request): None}
        )
        ff.run()
else:
    print("Gracias por usar el programa")
```

Solo me falta que el programa pueda manejar la entrada de los vídeos en los 3 formatos principales que anteriormente he mencionado y lo tendría terminado. Si alguien me hecha un cable le estaría agradecido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que estás delegando en `youtube-dl` la descarga del vídeo, puedes aprovechar y pasarle a ese comando las opciones `--extract-audio` y `--audio-format`, y de este modo te evitas el problema que estás planteando, a la vez que evitas la dependencia de la biblioteca `ffmpy` (aunque necesitarás tener instalado `ffmpeg` de todas formas, pues `youtube-dl` lo usa).

Es decir, podrías hacer algo así:

```
# Omitida la parte en que se busca la url del vídeo o se le pide al usuario
# Se supone que en la variable `url` ya la tenemos
convertir = input("Quedarse sólo con el audio? [S/n]: ").lower()
extra = ""
if convertir == "s" or convertir == "":
    formato = input("Formato del audio? [mp3]: ").lower()
    if formato == "":
        formato = "mp3"
    extra = "--extract-audio --audio-format {}".format(formato)

comando = "youtube-dl.py {} -o %\(title\)s.%\(ext\)s {}".format(url, extra)
subprocess.call(comando, shell=True)
print("Gracias por usar el programa")
```

Los formatos que puedes pedirle a `youtube-dl` son "aac","flac", "mp3", "m4a", "opus", "vorbis", o "wav".